# Prevent other applications moving behind AppBar -WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, appbar

I've developed a WPF application as an AppBar using vb.net, it's docked to the bottom edge of the screen and remains topmost as expected.

Other applications such as notepad when maximized/opened only expand to the top edge of the AppBar(expected). However when another application such as notepad is resized it can be dragged down behind the AppBar.

How do I prevent Other applications from moving behind the AppBar/prevent them moving into that section of screen that the AppBar occupies when they are not maximized?

Images 1 : the reserved space for the app bar and the VS window maximising to the edge of this reserved space, no further.

Image 2 : What I want to prevent, A resized window such as the chrome window being able to move into the reserved space for the AppBar.

[image: reserved space for the AppBar below VS] [image: I want to prevent a resized window moving into the reserved space]

Comment: What do you mean by 'prevent'? should they apear over your appBar, or should they be stop resize when over your app? If second, you could try with 'mouseMove' event, and firing This.Focus();

Comment: They should stop resize when they encroach on the area of the screen that has been reserved by the AppBar. Thanks, I'll try out using mouseMove and this.Focus()